# Prove that $f^{(n)}(0)$=0 for all $n$, given smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(\frac{1}{i}) =0$ for all natural number i.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm considering to prove it inductively. Using Rolle's theorem to get that $f'(y)=0$ for y between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then I have $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1})=0$, thus $\lim\limits_{y\to 0} f'(y)=0=f'(0)$. Then I also have $y_{1} < y_{2}$ s.t. $f'(y_{1})=f'(y_{2})=\cdots=0$, then I'll have $f''(z_{1})=f''(z_{2})=\cdots=0$. Repeat the steps above until I get $f^(n)(0)=0$
However, I'm not sure if I can do the limit like this. Thank you!

Comment: This argument is correct. You are just using continuity of the derivatives of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit arguments seems correct :

You can restrict to $I_{n} = [\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}]$ where by hypothesis $f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(\frac{1}{n+1}) = 0$, since $f$ is smooth, by Rolle theorem you get that $\exists \hspace{0.1cm} c \in (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1})$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

Since $f$ is at least $C^{1}([\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}]) \hspace{0.1cm} \forall \hspace{0.1cm} n$, with $c \in (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1})$  we have that $\lim\limits_{c \to 0} f'(c) = f'(0) = 0$